# preconditions for a 64Bit virtual system

Tags: 64-bit, virtual-pc

I just need to install Windows 2008 64Bit on a virtual machine. How to??? Do I need a special type of processor? Do I need a "special" virtualization tool? Actually installation fails on startup with the message that the CPU is not able to handle a 64Bit system.
host system: Windows 7 64Bit
CPU: Pentium D (seems to be Smithfield 805)

Comment: This is not a programming question. You may be better off asking at superuser.com or maybe serverfault.com.

Answer (score 0):

You need a 64-bit capable processor.  VMware / Hyper-V don't emulate CPUs, they execute on them.  You don't mention what hypervisor you're using.

Answer (score 0):

I tried Virtual PC 2007 and VirtualBox. Installation stopped with following information:
File: \windows\system32\boot\winload.exe
Status: 0xc000035a
Info: Attempting to load a 64-bit application, however this CPU is not compatible with 64-bit mode.

Comment: Not familiar with Virtual PC or VisualBox.  I'm guessing these are both "installed on windows" hypervisors?  If so, are you running Windows x64 ?   Theoretically, this shouldn't matter, but I'm intrigued.